# Unsupported Media Type 415 Error on Angular 7

Tags: .net-core, angular7, webservice-client, webapi

I made an admin panel using Angular 7 and I checked admin access. I am tring to upload from Pc to panel/database .I confused about what I should use for it. And also, when I try to upload image from pc to admin panel on Angular side(I used fileuploader library).I get error which is called Unsupported Media Type 415 .How can I upload image or file to database(I mean image will be shown on admin panel) from PC?

Answer (score 0):

It is solved when adding [FromForm] to front of model which I get from [HttpPost] function at .Net Core

(ıf we dont write the code which is up , it will expect application/JSON )